# Swift 4 UIButton attach on a View

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift3, uibutton

My problem is the following:
I am practicing in swift 4 and for this I am making an app to show my current position and have a SideMenu.

I have managed to make the lateral menu unfold and close with the + button that is in `NavBar`, but at the time of add a `UIButton` to perform other actions the button is superimposed on all layers and does not go with the view.

**Attached screenshots of the app, and some views of how I have the storyboard in xcode:**

pd: is `Swift 4` and the latest version of `Xcode`

[image: Xcode]

[image: AppScreen1]

[image: AppScreen2]

Comment: Welcom to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set your `menuView`'s `clipsToBounds` property to `true` it is `false` by default. When `false` a view's subviews will be displayed even if they are outside the view's bounds. You're also missing a constraint on your button. Auto layout can determine its x position but not it's y. Add a `top`, `bottom`, or `centerY` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

> the button is superimposed on all layers and does not go with the view.

It sounds like the button is probably constrained to `View` or `Google Maps View` instead of `Menuview`, so that the button maintains it's position relative to those views even when `Menuview` moves. Change the constraints so that the button is constrained to `Menuview`, and the button should then move when `Menuview` moves.